# Attach a table* to the bottom of a page

Tags: tables

I currently have

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[bp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|} 
\hline
Dekan        & Prof. Dr. med. & ............................................................  \\ 
\hline
1. Gutachter & Prof. Dr. med. & ............................................................  \\ 
\hline
2. Gutacher  & Prof. Dr. med. & ............................................................  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

And want to attach the table to the very bottom of the page - unfortunately to no avail yet. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why would you need a `table*`here? Your document, at least currently, uses only one column text. Will you add some more contents on the page? If not, probably something along the lines of `\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|} 
\hline
Dekan        & Prof. Dr. med. & ............................................................  \\ 
\hline
1. Gutachter & Prof. Dr. med. & ............................................................  \\ 
\hline
2. Gutacher  & Prof. Dr. med. & ............................................................  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}` works?

Comment: @leandriis: Exactly what I needed - put it as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\vspace*{\fill}` without the `table*` environment should work in order to bottom align the tabular. In the following MWE, I also included two other, alternative tables based on `\dotfill` instead of `.....`, as well as a textwidth-wide variant using `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{\fill} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|} 
\hline
Dekan        & Prof. Dr. med. & ............................................................  \\ 
\hline
1. Gutachter & Prof. Dr. med. & ............................................................  \\ 
\hline
2. Gutacher  & Prof. Dr. med. & ............................................................  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\clearpage

\vspace*{\fill} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|p{5cm}|} 
\hline
Dekan        & Prof. Dr. med. & \dotfill  \\ 
\hline
1. Gutachter & Prof. Dr. med. & \dotfill  \\ 
\hline
2. Gutacher  & Prof. Dr. med. & \dotfill  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\clearpage

\vspace*{\fill} 
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|l|X|} 
\hline
Dekan        & Prof. Dr. med. & \dotfill  \\ 
\hline
1. Gutachter & Prof. Dr. med. & \dotfill  \\ 
\hline
2. Gutacher  & Prof. Dr. med. & \dotfill  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you - and thanks for the `\dotfill` - did not know that.